# How to check which variables contains array of pointers in CLion gebugger?

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, clion

While I was exploring this question, I found out that it is simply possible with mac gdb, but I'm not sure that this functionality is accessible in CLion native debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please use the title as a *summary* of your problem, and put the main description and the question itself inside the body of your question. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Also note that CLion doesn't have neither a native compiler nor a native debugger. For compiler it uses whatever's on your system, and for compiler it typically comes with the Clang lldb bundled, or can be configured to use either the system lldb or gdb.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.